# Where are the PHP 5.2.4 Source Files?

Tags: ubuntu, php, version-control

I would like to get the source files for PHP 5.2.4.  Where are they?  I would think php.net but I could not find them on the web.  I tried using Tortoise/SVN to connect to the php.net repository but it required a passowrd given to developers.

Or a more difficult question - How do I install PHP 5.2.4 on Ubuntu Linux 10.10?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.4.tar.gz & use dpkg-buildpackage to build a deb & then install the deb.  For future note... it wouldn't hurt to look at their [releases page](http://www.php.net/releases/) for that kind of stuff.

That being said... why the old version? why not use the latest 5.3.6?  Why not use the ubuntu repository package (at version 5.3.3)?

Comment: There are quite a few php apps with compatibility issues with php 5.3, but if he is looking to stay in the 5.2 tree, probably ought to go with 5.2.17.

Comment: This is a correlation for another system - call it system A. I am matching my system up with their system as close as possible. One issue I had was goto which was not introduced 'til 5.3.0, therfore an algorithm I used form Knuth did not work on System A. Don't know what type of 'nix system they are using.

Comment: I read one googled article suggesting that a LAMP systems should be installed via DSOs (Dynamic Shared Objects) to reduce dependencies, however I was not sure if the article was dated. Is this relevant?

Comment: The geekstuff.com has 3 tutorials that explain how to install from source Apache, MySQL, and PHP. Went with the default configurations used in the tutorials b.c. I don't have time to research all the different options (they did include DSO support for Apache). Both are working great. This is the best site I've found for Linux related tutorials. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/instruction-guide-to-install-php5-from-source-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

See the PHP [Historical Releases](http://www.php.net/releases/) page.